# How do i report to toolStripStatusLabel text a string value using a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this method i want to make the report:

```
private int reportingmethod()
{
   if (result.Contains("forumPage"))
                        {
                            toolStripStatusLabel1
                            int index2 = result.IndexOf("\" text");
                            result = result.Remove(index2);
                            Names.Add(result);
                        }
}
```

I want to report the value in the variable result.

In backgroundworker dowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            reportingmethod();
        }
```

And a button click event that start the backgrounworker:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Then in the background progress changed event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
        }
```

First i'm not sure getting the Result like i did in the progress changed event is the right way.

Second how do i pass the result from the Do Work event ?

And third how do i report the result value from the reportingmethod ?

I never used before this toolStripStatusLabel with backgroundworker.

Comment: The worker calls `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress`, the UI receives the `ProgressChanged` event.  Lots of examples and tutorials if you just search for `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: your reportingmethod won't compile...

Comment: the event arg needs to be passed to your reporting method and then you can pull off whatever data you need from the event args.

Answer (score -3):

You need to disable this property:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

Then you can edit any value while the worker is running.

Comment: Disabling the check doesn't make them any less illegal.

Comment: If this property property is true , then he is not going to be able to edit the controls property while the Background worker is running.